# On a single core machine, how can a kernel impose restrictions (memory, etc) on a process, if the compiled code is directly executed on the processor?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

Basically, how does the kernel prevent me from doing something like this?

```
char *p = (char *) 0xfea80650; // or any random point in memory
*p = 0;
```

What I'm trying to get at is, only one thing can be running on the processor at a time. So when it is this programs turn, what could stop it?

Answer (score 3):

Modern machines use virtual memory management to map the addresses used by a program into real addresses in the DRAM.  So if you haven't allocated memory at that address, there won't be any entry in the address translation table, and the virtual memory manager will boot you off the system.

Comment: I see. Is this virtual memory manager implemented in hardware? I don't understand how it can possibly act to stop the instruction when the processor is busy with the very same instruction.

Comment: @user3483247: The memory manager is part of the processor, and all requests for memory accesses go through it. If a request violates the page table, a fault (which I think -- not sure -- is a type of hardware interrupt) is signaled.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, in a way. The kernel can't stop you from doing that, unless the processor has a feature to stop you from doing that - in which case the kernel can activate the processor feature. All modern desktop/laptop/server computers have processors with such features. Not *all* computers, though - embedded processors, which are very commonly used in devices like dishwashers, have no need for any protection features.

Before every memory access, the processor looks up the memory address in a data structure called the "page table". Each process has its own page table. The page table determines which virtual addresses (what your program uses) map to which physical addresses (which parts of which RAM chips).

In your example, the processor will look up `0xfea80650` in the page table. It will probably see that this virtual address is not allocated - i.e. it hasn't been told which part of which RAM chip corresponds to this address. So it will crash your program. Actually, the processor doesn't crash your program. The processor just calls a function in the kernel so the kernel knows a program accessed an invalid address. The kernel will stop your program and print an error message, because there's nothing else it can do that's sensible.

Alternatively, the kernel might be using address `0xfea80650`. The processor will look up the address in the page table, and see that only the kernel is allowed to access it, and see that you're not the kernel. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel does not prevent you from modifying it, the processor prevents you from modifying certain memory locations according to instructions that the kernel leaves it in a protected data structure called the page table. When the currently executing code violates one of these rules, the processor switches back into protected mode and tells the kernel to allow the kernel to do as it pleases.

Comment: Makes sense. How about the case where I flip a gpio pin, does the processor alert the kernel in that case as well?

Comment: @user3483247: I don't know much about the physical and electrical hardware, but from what I gather from the wikipedia article, which mentions that GPIO pins can be used as an IRQ (an interrupt identifier, basically), I think yes would be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As `user3386109` mentioned, you would be using virtual memory.  Virtual memory is handled by hardware.  When your machine tries to access memory which is not in its virtual memory translation table, it will generate a hardware interrupt.  This will stop your userspace program from running immediately, and switch execution over to the interrupt handler.  The interrupt handler in turn schedules a Linux bottom half to run.  The Bottom Half knows that the userspace program tried to access an invalid memory location, so it kills the userspace app, and causes the scheduler to reschedule the next highest priority userspace app.   So when the bottom half exits, the original userspace app will never run again.